# ngrok to work for a site located in different IP( i.e. remote server)

Tags: ngrok

I want to run a site which is on my different server with a host name.What can be the ngrok syntax.I tried running ngrok http -host-header=abc.com 80.But it shows tunnel not available.What can be the syntax for running  a website which is located on remote server from my local machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the feature of forwarding to servers running on a different machine.

Take a look at the documentation here:

https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/non-local (updated)

You should just be able to specify a network address and port instead of just a port with this command:

```
ngrok http 192.168.1.1:8080
```

Comment: @Loathian answer is still valid, but the docs have been moved to https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/non-local.

Comment: It has been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74364773/5211833) that the docs have been moved to https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/non-local